# I have an object that contains multiple Blob url's for playing audio, how do I select different url's and audios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, blob, html5-audio

As the title states, I have an object that contains multiple audio blobs stored in the "urls" variable, please see "generatedaudios.jsx" below. This is the console.log output of the "urls" variable object.[image]

Here I am fetching my "generated audios"

```
// Getting the generated audios for a user
 const generatedAudios = async () => {
  if (user) {
    let userEmail = user.email;

    const { data, error } = await supabase
    .storage
    .from("audios")
    .list(userEmail)


    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error displaying audio files from ${userEmail} storage:`, error);
    } else {
      console.log("listed audio files from storage:", data);

      // Updating state with the downloaded audio files
      setAudioFiles(data);
      console.log("audiofiles state:", audioFiles)
    }
  }

};

// display generated audios
useEffect(() => {
  generatedAudios();
},[]);
```

Here I am rendering them

```
{/* Displaying already generated audios */}
        <div id="generated" className="pl-[10%] pt-[7.5%]">
            <Card id="generated-card" className="w-[450px] h-[73.5%]">
              <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle>Generated clones</CardTitle>
                <CardDescription>Here you can see your already generated clones.</CardDescription>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardContent className="space-y-3">
                {audioFiles.length > 0 ? (
                  audioFiles.map((file) => {
                  // Only return the component if the file name is not ".emptyFolderPlaceholder"
                  if (file.name !== '.emptyFolderPlaceholder') {
                    // Separating name from rest of string
                    const nameOnly = file.name.split("-")[0];
                    return (
                      <GeneratedClones 
                        key={file.name}
                        name={nameOnly}
                        timestamp={file.updated_at}
                        metadata={file.metadata}
                        id={file.id}
                      />
                    )
                  }
                  })
                ) : <p>you currently have no generated clones :(</p>
              }
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </div>
```

This is what this looks like visually[image]

The problem is I have no idea how to get the audio to play, here is my generatedaudios.jsx

```
const GeneratedClones = ({ name, timestamp, id }) => {
    
  // Using stuff
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const { user } = useUser();

  const audioRef = useRef();
  const [playAudio, setPlayAudio] = useState(false);

  let urls = {};

  // Getting audio url from storage metadata to make audio playable
  const getAudioUrl = async () => {

    if (user) {
    let userEmail = user.email;
    // Listing audio id's from storage
    const { data: ids, error: listError } = await supabase
    .storage
    .from("audios")
    .list(userEmail)
    
    if (listError) {
      console.log("Error listing ids from storage", listError);
    } else {
      // loop over ids array
      for (let id of ids) {
        const { data: file, error: downloadError } = await supabase
          .storage
          .from("audios")
          .download(`${userEmail}/${id.name}`)

          if (downloadError) {
            console.error("There was an error downloading audios", downloadError);
          } else {
            // Create URL object from file data
            urls[id.name] = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            console.log(urls)
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAudioUrl();
  }, []);

  // If the play svg is clicked, play or pause audio
  const handlePlayClick = (id) => {
    setPlayAudio(prevAudio => !prevAudio);
    console.log("Audio playing in generated?", playAudio);

    const url = urls[id];
    console.log(url)
  
    if (playAudio) {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    } else {
      audioRef.current.play();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="pt-2">
        <CardContent>
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <div id="generated-svg" className="pr-4" onClick={handlePlayClick}>
              {playAudio === true ? (
                <svg fill="#000000" height="65px" width="65px" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 512 512" stroke="#000000"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" strokeWidth="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M256,0C114.617,0,0,114.615,0,256s114.617,256,256,256s256-114.615,256-256S397.383,0,256,0z M224,320 c0,8.836-7.164,16-16,16h-32c-8.836,0-16-7.164-16-16V192c0-8.836,7.164-16,16-16h32c8.836,0,16,7.164,16,16V320z M352,320 c0,8.836-7.164,16-16,16h-32c-8.836,0-16-7.164-16-16V192c0-8.836,7.164-16,16-16h32c8.836,0,16,7.164,16,16V320z"></path> </g></svg> 
              ) : <svg width={65} height={65} fill="#000000" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 408.221 408.221" stroke="#000000"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" strokeWidth="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <g> <g> <path d="M204.11,0C91.388,0,0,91.388,0,204.111c0,112.725,91.388,204.11,204.11,204.11c112.729,0,204.11-91.385,204.11-204.11 C408.221,91.388,316.839,0,204.11,0z M286.547,229.971l-126.368,72.471c-17.003,9.75-30.781,1.763-30.781-17.834V140.012 c0-19.602,13.777-27.575,30.781-17.827l126.368,72.466C303.551,204.403,303.551,220.217,286.547,229.971z"></path> </g> </g> </g></svg>
            }
            </div>
            <div id="generated-content">
              <h2 id="name" className="font-semibold text-2xl">{name}</h2>
              <p className="text-muted-foreground">Created at {timestamp}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <></>
      <audio 
        ref={audioRef}
        src={urls[id.name]}
      />
    </div>
  )
};

export default GeneratedClones;
```

What do I need to do? Track which audio button is clicked somehow? Or what? Currently nothing is being played when clicking either of the play buttons pictured above. I figure this line         `src={urls[id.name]}` is complete nonsense.

Any help or general roasting of my code (help preferred) would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you get one file to play? i.e scrap the multiple files. If not, do that first

Comment: @fdcpp Nope not working.

Comment: can you get it to play as a static file? i.e. just have the file resaved on a test page and play it? can you then call that file up dynamically? can you get any static blob data to play?

Comment: Are you able to create a test site of the above and put it in a location for others to see? GitHub pages, jsfiddle etc

Comment: Also, if your system does not work with one file, it is not going to work with three. Simplify what you are doing first _then_ make it more complex. Keep simplifying until you can get something to work and then you will have a better understanding of the problem your are trying to solve